# Sourcetree cannot refresh OAuth token, I get error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

When using Atlassian's Sourcetree I try and and "Refresh OAuth Token" and I see this error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue here is we were developing a website that sets the HSTS header such that all localhost requests now require HTTPS.

The work-around is to remove localhost from your domain security policies.
If Chrome is your browser, you can do that here: chrome://net-internals/#hsts
Under the heading **Delete domain security policies** enter `localhost` in the 'domain' input and press `delete`

Now try and "Refresh OAuth Token" again.

Comment: I had this exact problem. Had been messing with HSTS during development of local websites, and now Sourcetree could no longer authenticate. Deleting the security policy for localhost worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome I had this issue, my workaround for this was:

1. Open an incognito Window
2. Paste in the localhost address and change HTTPS to HTTP
3. Refresh page and I'm authenticated

I'm on SourceTree version 3.3.8

Comment: The answer with more votes did not work for me, but this one did. Thanks a lot!